# Topological Insulator vs Topological Band Insulator

Tags: topological-insulators

Is there any conceptual difference between topological insulator (TI), and topological band insulator (TBI)? And if there is, what would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Topological insulators are materials which are insulating in the bulk, but have conducting states on their surface. These can be realized even in *strongly correlated systems* where the band theory of solids does not hold.

Topological band insulators form a subset of topological insulators which can be described using band theory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Heisenberg!!

Comment: Do you know any book or bibliographic source to go deeper into the subject?

Comment: If you want to dig deeper into topological insulators, to start with I would suggest [Bernevig's](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Topological_Insulators_and_Topological_S/_7r_UqFN0IEC?hl=en&gbpv=0) book. This is essentially band theory. Interacting topological insulators are relatively new and currently a subject of intense research. Here is a [review](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6633/aad6a6) article. Disclaimer: I know nothing about your background, so pardon me if this isn't helpful.